# Can ionic cordova build android is execute by www-data?

Tags: linux, laravel, cordova, ionic-framework

So my working with my project with requires this kind of capable, i combined laravel and ionic and call ionic /www folder from laravel public and its working great, but my project is actually want to directly convert this www to apk which is like online ‘appbuilder’, so i made a route that execute ionic using exec command from php, what am tryting to execute is ionic cordova build android, so whenever user go to this route it will directly generate and download the apk, i have read all the stackoverflow topic related to this issue but nothing works. I know that whenever we execute from exec(), shell_exec() and backticks operator the user that actually run this is www-data, and this www-data has a lot of problem with permission

i got below error when i try to run ionic cordova build android using www-data:

using this command: sudo -u www-data ionic cordova build android (why did i do this, because if i run from web browser it will pop 504 error which is bad idea cus i can’t see the error)

```
shell.js: internal error
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml'
at Object.chmodSync (fs.js:1023:3)
at copyFileSync (/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:41:6)
at /var/www/html/instantapp- inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:201:5
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object._cp (/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:157:11)
at Object.cp (/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:186:23)
at updateConfigFilesFrom (/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/lib/prepare.js:98:11)
at Api.module.exports.prepare (/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/lib/prepare.js:42:20)
at Api.prepare (/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:192:45)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:105:36
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

before i got above error i changed the config.xml permission under platforms/android/app/src/res/xml to 777, but if change it back to 666, the error will look like this:

```
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml

EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/html/instantapp-inovidea/public/mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml'
```

idk what permission to let to www-data to be able to execute this ionic cordova command, any help would be great, thanks

ps: sorry if my english is not good, im trying my best to explain everything.